# segue UiTabBar to UiTabBar

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

I can't move from one page to another without losing the tabBarController

I use a didSelectRow and I can recover the data as well as change the page except that the tabBar menu of my view is not displayed

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let storagepasse: String

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)

        storagepasse = storages[indexPath.row].id!
        print(storagepasse)
       let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       let secondView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GestionStorage") as! InformationStorageController
       secondView.infoStorage = storagepasse
      self.present(secondView, animated: true,completion: nil)
    }
```

[StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us5Bz.png)

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmt3m.jpg)

Comment: `present` literally presents a new viewController on top of the current one. Whichever views are behind it will never be shown. Try to use `navigationController.push(....)` and the `tabBar` will be kept.

Answer (score 0):

Check modalPresentationStyle property in vc(secondView). You need something like .currentContext or .overCurrentContext.

Comment: Thank you, but your solution didn't work in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use push view controller instead of presenting it.

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondView, animated: true)
```

You can also add this.

```
self.navigationController?.tabBarController?.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
```

Comment: thank you for your help :)
I didn't get the ideal result, at least I keep a tabBar menu that will be enough for my project